# what's wrong with indexOf in this code? why I get -1 when I try to print indexOf answer1?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        ArrayList<String>line1=new ArrayList<String>();
        line1.add("el marg");
        line1.add("ezbt el nakhl");
        line1.add("ain shams");
        line1.add("el matria");
        line1.add("el helmia");
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Entry Station");
        String answer1=s.next();
        Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Exit Station");
        String answer2=a.next();

        System.out.println(line1.subList(line1.indexOf(answer1),line1.indexOf(answer2)));
    }
}
```

I want to print a sublist of the train station which between entry station an exit station, but sometinh wrong it gives me -1 even if the user typed a station in the arraylist

Comment: Note that you don't need multiple instances of `Scanner` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your station names have spaces.

`s.next()` will read the next token from the `Scanner`, which won't have a space in it.

Use `s.nextLine()` instead.

---

As a general tip for debugging such a problem, try viewing the values of `answer1` and `answer2` in your debugger (or even just print them out). It should then be very obvious why it's not matching.

Answer (score 0):

verify the station name what you write in terminal. Because the -1 value is returned when idexOf not find the word.  Print the station name of  write terminal  and analise the white spaces or Enter that may be being added in the answer1 variable and answer2